# Numero de botones segun opciones

Tags: javascript, c#

Estoy realizando un tipo encuesta, donde en mi base de datos tengo mi pregunta y mis posibles opciones que pueden ser hasta 5, estas opciones de transforman en botones del lado web, pero hay algunas preguntas que solo es necesario 2 opciones.

> Ejemplo:
>
> Genero
> a) Hombre | b) Mujer

Pero en vez de eso me sale de la siguiente manera

> Genero
>
> a) Hombre | b)Mujer | c) | d)

Como se puede ver, si me manda mis 2 posibles opciones hombre-mujer pero ademas me crea los otros botones para las demas opciones que no existen en esta pregunta.

Mi pregunta es, como puedo verficar las preguntas y crear las opciones correctas para cada una?

Codigo.

```
function Cargar(X) {
    x= x;
    $.ajax({
        url: "Default.aspx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "action=request&x=" + x,
        success: function (data) {
            
            if (data.length > 0) {

                var inner = "";

                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                    
                  
                    if (data[i].EXP_RESP_UNO.indexOf('/') > -1) {
                        //CREACION DE BOTONES
                        inner = "<div class=\"jumbotron Page" + i + "\">" +
                            "<div class=\"row\">" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-12 text-center\">" +
                            "<img src=\"Media/logo.png\" />" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"row\">" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-12 text-center\">" +
                            "<h6 id=\"pregunta" + i + "\">" + (i + 1) + ".- " + data[i].EXP_PREGUNTA + "</h6>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"row\">" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                            "<div> A) <button id=\"p" + i + "o1\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA1 + "\"></p></div > " +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                            "<div> B) <button id=\"p" + i + "o2\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA2 + "\"></div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                            "<div> <p>C) <button id=\"p" + i + "o3\"class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA3 + "\"></p></div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                            "<br>" +
                            "<div> D) <button id=\"p" + i + "o4\"class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA4 + "\"></div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                            "<br>" +
                            "<div> E) <button id=\"p" + i + "o5\"class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA5 + "\"></div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>" +
                            "</div>";

                        correctas.push(data[i].CORRECTA);
                    }
```

Comment: A como van las cosas, tal vez necesites `tinyint` para "Genero"; al parecer `bit` ya no es suficiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto deberia ayudar.

Debajo, a partir de `RESPUESTA2`, hay una condicion `!data[i].RESPUESTA2` para cada respuesta de forma que NO concatene el `div` de la respuesta si esta vacia.

Por cada pregunta, hago algo como esto:

```
(!data[i].RESPUESTA2 ? '' :
      "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
      "<div> B) <button id=\"p" + i + "o2\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA2 + "\">
       </div>" +
      "</div>")
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { if (data[i].EXP_RESP_UNO.indexOf('/')> -1) {
         //CREACION DE BOTONES
         inner = "<div class=\"jumbotron Page" + i + "\">" +
            "<div class=\"row\">" +
               "<div class=\"col-sm-12 text-center\">" +
                  "<img src=\"Media/logo.png\" />" +
                  "</div>" +
               "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"row\">" +
               "<div class=\"col-sm-12 text-center\">" +
                  "<h6 id=\"pregunta" + i + "\">" + (i + 1) + ".- " + data[i].EXP_PREGUNTA + "</h6>" +
                  "</div>" +
               "</div>" +
            "<div class=\"row\">" +
               "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                  "<div> A) <button id=\"p" + i + "o1\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA1 + "\">
                        </p>
                  </div> " +
                  "</div>" +
               (!data[i].RESPUESTA2 ? '' :
               "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                  "<div> B) <button id=\"p" + i + "o2\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA2 + "\">
                  </div>" +
                  "</div>") +
               (!data[i].RESPUESTA3 ? '' :
               "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                  "<div>
                     <p>C) <button id=\"p" + i + "o3\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA3 + "\"></p>
                  </div>" +
                  "</div>") +
               (!data[i].RESPUESTA4 ? '' :
               "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<div> D) <button id=\"p" + i + "o4\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA4 + "\">
                  </div>" +
                  "</div>") +
               (!data[i].RESPUESTA5 ? '' :
               "<div class=\"col-sm-2 col-sm-offset-2 text-center\">" +
                  "<br>" +
                  "<div> E) <button id=\"p" + i + "o5\" class=\"btn btn-success btn-lg\"" + data[i].RESPUESTA5 + "\">
                  </div>" +
                  "</div>") +
               "</div>" +
            "</div>";

         correctas.push(data[i].CORRECTA);
}
```

Comment: Por favor explica tu código. Saludos.